# Setting cookie to keep user logged in for six months

Tags: php, cookies

Below is my login PHP code.  How can I set a cookie to make the browser keep user logged in for 6 months, even if they close their browser?

```
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    // user is not logged in.
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        // retrieve the username and password sent from login form & check the login.
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();
```

Comment: here is a comment of me, what have you done?

Comment: $inTwoMonths = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 + time();
setcookie('cmdlogin', 'cmdlogin', $inTwoMonths );  and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
// set cookie
// setcookie(name,value,expire);

$expire = 6*30*24*3600;
setcookie('username',_POST['username'], $expire);

// get cookie
$_COOKIE['username'];
```

Security Vulnerability DO NOT USE:

```
setcookie('password',_POST['password'],$expire);
```

Comment: `@user3221728`, return once then indent 4 spaces to show code. And it's `$_POST`, not `_POST`.

Comment: Password > Never include password in a cookie!

Comment: This isn't setting the exiration time properly. Expiration is an epoch timestamp, so needs to be `time() + $expire` in your case

Answer (score 1):

Oh no. Never EVER include password in a cookie. When using php, use session functions.

```
session_start();
// Do login here
$_SESSION["username"] = $yourusername;
```

when you want to check if user has logged in, query data for `$_SESSION` username variable.
Only thing it saves is cookie named PHP_SESSID, with data of a random string. User can't modify `session` variables, because it is prosessed server-side.